# Algorithm for task assigning

Tags: java, algorithm, spring-mvc, data-structures

I have 5 activity-cases to be mapped to 2
 users and my senior suggested to use round robin algorithm to do this

Like 1st case - 1st user

2nd case - 2nd user

3rd case - 1st user

4th case - 2nd user

5th case - 1st user

I want to know , is there any other algorithm best suited for such scenarios ?

Comment: Is it just a assignment task or users need to complete each activity before he can take new activity?

Comment: Define "best suited". Many algorithms are possible, including unfair ones like giving all cases to user 1.

Comment: Hi Ravi -- its an assignment task , there is no completion activity to be monitored , only putting x tasks on each user's bucket

Comment: Hi Henry -- best suited in the sense no user should sit idle , also no user should be overloaded with tasks

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind as well is a _queue_ where you just pull the next task and assign it to a user when he has completed his previous one (or has currently none assigned).

Comment: If you are asking  for a better algorithm, then you may want to state in what ways do you expect other suggested solutions to be "better". Better in terms of efficiency...etc?

Comment: Hi user3437460 , i meant better in terms of load balancing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears analogous to process scheduling to me, so you might find my answer more along that track.

**Case 1: All activities are equally important**

With this assumption, RR is the good enough scheduling algorithm.

**Case 2: Each activity has a priority**

Most scheduling problems that occur in real-world come under this case.
I'm considering priority is proportional to time taken to complete activity, I can think of:

- Shortest job first
- Priority - based scheduling

**Recommended Reading:**

Modern Operating Systems (4th Edition) by A.S.Tanenbaum - Section 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Round robin is probably your best choice if you want the number of cases to be the same for each user. Unless someone works more efficiently and you want to give them more work, then I would just stick with that.